# 1px gap in row using CSS Grid

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a custom css grid:

```
.row
  box-sizing: border-box
  background-color: tomato
  font-size: 0
.row:after
  content: ""
  display: table
  clear: both
[class*="col-"]
  float: left
  min-height: 1px
  box-sizing: border-box
.col-1-4
  width: 25%
.col-3-4
  width: 75%
.col-2-3
  width: 66.66667%
.col-1-3
  width: 33.33333%
```

But when I'm zooming page a 1px gap appear in the end of row:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5hQs.png)

So how can this be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is just a rounding error. See also: [Fixing Sub-Pixel rounding issue in a CSS Fluid Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9635347/3162554)

You can avoid this by giving the last column in a row `width: auto`.