# height property not being applied equally to all divs with equal heights

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

There's a very strange problem that i am facing in a webpage that i am designing.
It's plain HTML and CSS and i am trying to create an animation at the bottom of each **anchor** element. All are of equal width of 25% since i am using a grid system but the lines underneath the **anchor** elements are showing a strange behavior where some of the lines are smaller in height than the others even though i've given equal height to all the **anchor** elements. A fixed height of lets say 3px works perfectly fine when given to the before element. It's the 5% value that's causing this and i have no idea why.

### [The screenshot of what's happening with the a elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqzrP.png)

```
.three-columns
{
    width: 25%;
}
a.listings
{

  font-family: "Consolas", 'Roboto', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2.5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  transition: color 0.5s 0s;
  position: relative;
}

a.listings::before
{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  height: 5%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: right 0.5s;
  transition: right 0.5s;
}

a.listings:hover::before
{
  right: 0;
}
```

---

**three-columns** is the **div** that contains the **a** elements with the class of **listings**

---

```
<div class="three-columns">
    <a class="listings" href="#">dd</a>
</div>
```

---

Also, when i inspect my code in Chrome and set the size to 1366 x 768 which is also the size of my laptop screen, it looks okay. As soon as i close the inspector and come back to the real size, it starts behaving as it shows in the screenshot i attached.

**Edit:** Okay no, even the inspector shows that same behavior now

Comment: Probably a rounding issue, as you have paddings of `2.5%`

Comment: thanks for the reply but removing the padding didn't solve it

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Percentage heights do not work the way you think they will.  Strongly suggest using `vw` and `vh` units instead.

Comment: actually it was the vw units that started this :P then i moved to percentages

Comment: It is a rounding issue. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635347/fixing-sub-pixel-rounding-issue-in-a-css-fluid-grid). Add `float:none;overflow: hidden;` to the `a.listing` style and it is gone.

Comment: i added those but nothing changed. It's the same in all the browsers that i have

Comment: You're right. In Firefox it was gone. Now tested it in Chrome and IE11 and it's still there. In Safari then again it works, in Opera it doesn't...

Comment: The same code that's causing this problem works perfectly fine when i inspect it and set the width to 1366px which is the same as the width of my screen and force the hover class on. I don't know why it's there and as soon as i inspect, it's gone.

Comment: okay, no. Now even the inspector shows that inconsistency

Comment: The only way to solve this is to set a fixed `height` in `a.listings::before`.  If I set it to `height:2px` the problems are gone in all browsers.

Comment: This is [an old post](http://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/), but it still is an issue apparently...

Comment: So I noticed that changing the number of rows seems to affect this behavior. Also, if you drop it down to 1% the variation becomes very clear. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gf476cyq/5/

Comment: Michel yes i mentioned that in the original post but that's not gonna be helpful for devices that go over 3000px in width...i am scaling the font sizes with increasing widths and that's gonna make that fixed height look very small..i'll check that post out and thank you very much for helping me out..At least i know that i didn't do anything super stupid

Comment: That's an awesome discovery Ryan...and i DO have a lot of rows on that webpage like over 26 i think so that may be causing the problem...